# Problem with [datetime]::ParseExact in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to update the script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229298/automatically-import-ics-file-to-outlook-com) to work with Office 365 exported calendar entries.

I changed the variable for DTSTART and DTEND (or rather I am trying to) because the new ICS files show the format as

```
DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T160000
DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T150000
```

My modification is

```
    $DSTART = ($data.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.Name -eq 'DSTART;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"' }).Value -replace "T"
    $DSTART = [datetime]::ParseExact($DSTART, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)

    $DTEND = ($data.GetEnumerator() | ?{ $_.Name -eq 'DTEND;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"' }).Value -replace "T"
    $DTEND = [datetime]::ParseExact($DTEND, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)
```

However, I am getting

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:28 char:5
+     $DSTART = [datetime]::ParseExact($DSTART, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
 
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:31 char:5
+     $DTEND = [datetime]::ParseExact($DTEND, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Thank you for your help :)
Alex

Comment: You're not accounting for the 'T' in the date-time strings.

Comment: Are you sure `$DSTART` doesn't contain additional information? Try inspecting it with `Write-Host "'$DSTART'"` (the literal `'` single-quotes will make it easier to spot trailing or leading spaces)

Comment: Further to @MathiasR.Jessen's comment, are you sure your ```$data``` contains an item (and only one item) with the appropriate ```Name``` property? If your ```where-object``` returns ```$null``` you might be trying to parse an empty string rather than ```20240111150000```, which gives the same error message as your post. In any case, logging the value of ```$DSTART``` to the console will give some more information...

Comment: Also, should ```$_.Name -eq 'DSTART;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\"``` be ```$_.Name -eq 'DSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"``` (i.e. without backslashes)? The quotes would be escaped in a source json file if that's where you loaded the data from - e.g. ```... value: "DSTART;TZID=\"W. Europe Standard Time\":20240111T160000\" ...``` but if you load that using ```ConvertFrom-Json``` the literal unescaped string value is ```DSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T160000```...

Comment: Ah, no, the file contains multiple DTSTART, but I thought my syntax selected one particular one.
```
DTSTART:16011028T030000
DTSTART:16010325T020000
DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240129T000000
```

After adding the "T" back to the datetime string, I get a different error (I thought my replace would take care of the missing T btw).

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Comment: Data is loaded as in the original script via
```
$ICSpath = "C:\outlooktest\"
$ICSlist = get-childitem $ICSPath

Foreach ($i in $ICSlist )
{
    $file = $i. FullName
    $data = @{}
    $content = Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8
    $content |
    foreach-Object {
        if($_.Contains(':')){
            $z = @{ $_.split( ':')[0] = ( $_.split( ':')[1]).Trim() }
            $data.Add($z.Keys, $z.Values)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The only *immediate* fix required is to remove the unnecessary (and conceptually incorrect) `\`-escaping of the `"` chars.:

```bash
    # Note the absence of \ before "

    $DSTART = ($data.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'DSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"' }).Value -replace "T"
    $DSTART = [datetime]::ParseExact($DSTART, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)

    $DTEND = ($data.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"' }).Value -replace "T"
    $DTEND = [datetime]::ParseExact($DTEND, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null)
```

- However, other pitfalls await, and the code can be optimized; see next section.

---

- Your immediate problem is the **unnecessary attempt to escape `"` chars. as `\"`**: inside [verbatim PowerShell string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`), `"` doesn't require escaping (and inside [expandable (interpolating) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), `"..."`, you'd need `` `" `` (or `""`) - in general, `\` does *not* serve as an escape char. in PowerShell, only `` ` `` (the so-called backtick) does).

  - As a result of this unnecessary escaping, your `?` ([`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)) filter didn't match anything, and you ultimately passed `$null` as the first argument to `[datetime]::ParseExact()`, which caused the error you saw.
  - Note that the reason the error didn't complain about a *null* argument is that PowerShell converts `$null` to the *empty string* in .NET method calls when binding `string`-typed parameters; passing an actual null requires use of `[NullString]::Value`.
    Thus, your calls were in effect equivalent to:

    ```bash
    # Predictably fails.
    [datetime]::ParseExact('', 'yyyyMMddHHmmss', $null)
    ```
- However, your code can be streamlined (as can the one in the linked post), albeit with *string* keys.

  - `$data` in your code is a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), i.e. a collection of key-value pairs, albeit constructed in a nonstandard way in the linked post, using *collections* as individual keys.

    - If you instead construct the hashtable as shown below, you do *not* need to enumerate *all* pairs (`.GetEnumerator()`) to find the ones of interest, but can access them *directly by key*, using either PowerShell's index syntax (`[...]`) or dot notation; e.g.:

      ```bash
      # -> '20240111T160000'
      $data['DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"']

      # Alternatively; same result.
      $data.'DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"'
      ```
  - See the self-contained sample code below.

    - Note: The code assumes the following:

      - It assumes that there are *no duplicate names* (keys) among the input lines; if there are, the value of the *last* duplicate wins.

        - Additionally, it assumes that the entries of interest are always present in the input hashtable; if that cannot be assumed, the `[datetime]::ParseExact()` call would have to be made conditional.
      - It assumes that no time-zone conversions are necessary: by using `[datetime]::Parse()`, as in your attempt, the input strings result in `[datetime]` instances whose `.Kind` property value is `Unspecified`, meaning that it represents an *abstract* point in time that is neither known to be a *local* nor a *UTC*-based one.

        - In effect, further processing of these `[datetime]` instances will only work as intended if (a) your machine's current time zone happens to be `W. Europe Standard Time` time too and (b) later processing on the same machine treats instances whose `.Kind` property value is `Unspecified` the same as if it were `Local`.

```bash
# Parse the simulated file lines into a hashtable (key-value pairs),
# as in the linked post.
$data = @{}
@'
DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T160000
DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T150000
'@ -split '\r?\n' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_ -split ':', 2
    $data[$key] = $value
  }

# Access the entries of interest *directly*, *by key*
# and parse them as dates.
# Also, no need to remove "T" from the value first - just integrate
# it into the date format string.
$dStart = [datetime]::ParseExact(
  $data['DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"'], 
  'yyyyMMddTHHmmss', 
  $null)

$dEnd = [datetime]::ParseExact(
  $data['DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"'],
  'yyyyMMddTHHmmss', 
  $null)

# Sample output of the result.
[pscustomobject] @{
  Start = $dStart
  End = $dEnd
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
That is very interesting. I did not dare mess with all of the original script as I figure the problem would be "small".

With your code adjustement I now successfully get a corret datetime.
However, I think due to my system being DD.MM.YYYY and $DTSTART being MM/DD/YYYY, it fails with `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'.
At line:35 char:5
+     $appt.Start = $DTSTART
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: Fixed it by adding toString.
`$DTEND = ([datetime]::ParseExact($data['DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time"'], 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss', $null)).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")`
MAybe there is a more elegant way, then I am happy to adjust. Maybe so everybody could use it irrlevant of what their system settings are?

Comment: @AleXSR700, glad to hear it, though regarding the original parsing I wonder whether there can be _multiple_ lines with the _same key values_, e.g. `DTEND;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time":20240111T160000`, in the input file. Is that a possibility? If so, the solution in this answer only provides the _last_ duplicate's value. As for the assignment to `$appt.Start`: What is the _full line_ that caused the problem? What data type does `$appt.Start` accept? Indeed, using a culture-specific format is not a good idea.

Comment: Solved it:
`ToString((Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)`

Comment: Regarding the unique nature of DTSTART: From the test files I created, there are always multiple DTSTART keys but so far only one "DTSTART;TZID="W. Europe Standard Time".

Comment: @AleXSR700, `.ToString('G')` is shorter, but I still wonder whether to-string conversion is actually required. If it is, `.ToString('o')` would give you the full precision in an ISO 8601-like format. Either way, the parsed-from-string `[datetime]` instances are ambiguous, as they are marked as neither UTC timestamps nor as local ones. Unless you happen to be in the `W. Europe Standard Time` time zone, you'd have to perform time-zone conversions first. All that said, I think this answer addresses your question _as asked_, follow-up problems notwithstanding.